# Render React Component at top

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, components, render

I'm new to React, but I couldn't find anything online about it. I don't understand what exactly the error is. First of all, I have a `PageComponent`.

This `PageComponent` has (relevant to this question) a function called `forceAddComponent`. This takes `componentData` and `data` as parameters.

The `componentData` is a dictionary that looks like this:

```json
{
    name: 'SomeComponentNameAsString',
    ref: referenceToAnExamComponent,
    component: <...Component/>
}
```

and you can see the `data`. However (no matter how I try), the new component is **ALWAYS added at the bottom**, not at the top of the other `examComponents`. I have tried unshift and also built new lists. Nothing has helped. Do any of you have an idea why React just renders it below the last one anyway?

The PageComponent.js:

```
import {Component, createRef} from "react";

export class PageComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            examComponents: [] // componentData
        }

        this.pageRef = createRef();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={'paper a4'} ref={this.pageRef}>
                {this.state.examComponents.map((componentData, _index) => {
                    return componentData.component;
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }

    scrollToPage() {
        // scroll to paper
        const top = this.pageRef.current.offsetTop;
        window.scrollTo({
            top: top - 80,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    }

    getSumOfHeightPagePadding(page) {
        const pageStyle = window.getComputedStyle(page);
        return parseInt(pageStyle.paddingTop) + parseInt(pageStyle.paddingBottom);
    }

    getRemainingHeight() {
        const maxHeight = this.getMaxHeight();
        const usedHeight = this.getUsedHeight();
        return maxHeight - usedHeight - this.getSumOfHeightPagePadding(this.pageRef.current);
    }

    tryAddComponent(componentData) {
        const maxHeight = this.getMaxHeight();
        // render component and wait for it to be rendered
        // this.pushComponent(component);
        const r = async () => {
            await this.pushComponent(componentData);

            const componentHeight = componentData.ref.current.getActualHeight();

            // check if component fits on page
            if (this.getUsedHeight() >= maxHeight) {
                // component is too big for this page
                // remove component from page
                this.popComponent(componentData.component);
                return {status: false, neededHeight: componentHeight};
            }

            return {status: true, neededHeight: componentHeight};
        };
        return r();
    }

    getMaxHeight() {
        // get max height of this page
        const pageStyle = window.getComputedStyle(this.pageRef.current);
        let height = parseInt(pageStyle.height);
        height -= this.getSumOfHeightPagePadding(this.pageRef.current);
        return height;
    }

    getUsedHeight = () => {
        // get height of all components in this page
        let height = 0;
        Object.keys(this.state.examComponents).forEach((key, _index) => {
            const component = this.state.examComponents[key];
            height += component.ref.current.getActualHeight();
        });
        return height;
    }

    forceAddComponent = async (componentData, data = {atTop: true}) => {
        await this.pushComponent(componentData, data);
    }

    getActualHeight() {
        // get height of this page
        return this.pageRef.current.clientHeight;
    }

    pushComponent(componentData, data = {atTop: false}) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            const newExamComponents = this.state.examComponents;
            if (data.atTop) {
                newExamComponents.unshift(componentData);
            } else {
                newExamComponents.push(componentData);
            }

            this.setState({examComponents: newExamComponents}, () => {
                resolve();
            });
        });
    }

    popComponent(component) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            examComponents: prevState.examComponents.filter((_, index) => {
                return component !== this.state.examComponents[index].component;
            })
        }));
    }
}
```